# How can I make the default sound input for Skype persistent?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, skype, alsa

In order for Skype to work with the mic in my webcam, I need to change the *sound preferences -> Input* to "0825 Analog Mono" (default is "Internal Audio Analog Stereo").  However whenever I reboot this gets reset.  How can I make it the default?

Comment: i would check the alsa docs

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this may be a bug in Ubuntu's integration of PulseAudio and alsa-utils.  We're investigating possible resolutions.

Comment: Any news on this topic? This bug is still existing in the newest Ubuntu version.

Comment: @danieltchen can you provide a link to the bug report?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look over at [How can my audio input always be the webcam microphone?](https://askubuntu.com/a/115575/44766) where I have just posted a way to make a webcam mic the default input whenever it is connected.

It is not super easy - you need to fiddle with udev rules and install a shell script, but it does work 100%