# How to set webcam microphone as default after its plugged in the USB?

Tags: pulseaudio, webcam, udev, systemd

At the first blush to achieve my goal I should use **udev**. Simple rule detects that webcam is connected and launches the script:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="046d", ATTR{idProduct}=="081b", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/webcam_hotplug_udev.sh"
```

The script sets some environment variables and launches **pacmd** to set default microphone:

```
#!/bin/bash
user_UID=1000
pulseaudio_user=pi
idvendor="046d"
idproduct="081b"
srcname=`sudo -u $pulseaudio_user XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$user_UID pacmd dump | grep "set-card-profile.*$idvendor.*$idproduct.*input" | sed -ne 's/.*\.\([^ ]*\) input:\(.*\)/alsa_input.\1.\2/p'`
sudo -u $pulseaudio_user XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$user_UID pacmd set-default-source $srcname
```

More convenient way to do this is described in [older answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/115575/578877) to the same question.

But something has changed in Ubuntu from that time.
Webcam microphone can be set to default only *after* the script from **udev** rule has finished execution.
I've tried to send the script to background with **&** and add some **sleep** before using **pacmd**. Same problem. Maybe It's related to **systemd**?