# Multiple Microphones/Speakers; how to select default?

Tags: sound

On a laptop I am using headphones, and the headphones are always attached to laptop. When I use Skype I need to switch every time after restart to headphone's microphone, but I do not need to switch to headphones because that settings stays somehow after restart. How to do that for microphone as well?

[After restart headphones stays as default output but microphone not as default input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch77b.png)

Comment: Have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/31206/how-can-my-audio-input-always-be-the-webcam-microphone

Comment: Thanks! How come I did not found this?